# ElasticSearch : MultiMatch with "match a list of values"

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I combine MultiMatch + "match a list of values" in a single query.

ie . I want to query a list of names `["John","Bas","Peter"]` against a list of fields `["first_name","Alias","nick_name","surname"]`

**-match a list of values-**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms": {
          "first_name": ["John","Bas","Peter"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**-MultiMatch-**

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query":    "john", 
    "fields": ["first_name","Alias","nick_name","surname"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple search terms to the `multi_match` as well:

```
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "John Bas Peter",
      "fields": [
        "first_name",
        "Alias",
        "nick_name",
        "surname"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Also, `multi_match` has various ways by which it's actually transforming internally the query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types

If you use the `_validate` API with this you could see how exactly ES is re-interpreting the query:

```
GET /_validate/query?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "John Bas Peter",
      "fields": [
        "first_name",
        "Alias",
        "nick_name",
        "surname"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above gives:

```
   "explanations": [
      {
         "index": "test",
         "valid": true,
         "explanation": "((Alias:john Alias:bas Alias:peter) | (surname:john surname:bas surname:peter) | (nick_name:john nick_name:bas nick_name:peter) | (first_name:john first_name:bas first_name:peter))"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?